# Как установить бинарники библиотеки Qt на сервер с Debian 11

Tags: qt, qtcreator, развертывание, deploy

В Debian 10 есть хороший пакет `qt5-default`. Его установка через `apt-get` решает все базовые зависимости для проектов, написанных с использованием Qt5. Версия, правда, там не первой свежести, но всё равно удобно.

Ныне разработка на Qt подразумевает безапелляционный онлайн установочник на машине программиста, большие оффлайн-пакеты не распространяются. С этим можно смириться и этот подход имеет свои плюсы в удобстве, НО что делать при деплое на Debian 11, в котором нет `qt5-default` (конечно, есть другие пакеты, связанные с Qt, которые можно нагуглить, но список очень сжатый). Главный вопрос: что делать с Qt 6, неужели нет удобного инструмента автоматической установки всего набора библиотек Qt из репозиториев?.. Этот вопрос касается в первую очередь Qt 6, но и для Qt 5 на Debian 11 тоже актуален.

Debian всё-таки является продакшн-системой, стабильной и всегда ранее удобной. Неужели с современным Qt какие-то трудности?.. Прошу открыть глаза на истину.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, в чем именно проблема, но, например 6 версию можно установить из тестовых реп [how-to-install-and-use-backports-in-debian-11-bullseye](https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-and-use-backports-in-debian-11-bullseye/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй это заклинание:

# apt install qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools qtchooser qt5-qmake

У меня на Debian-11 помогло.